# React merge two arrays in useState not working

Tags: reactjs

Have useState

```
const [pending, setPending] = useState([]);
```

and two place where I putting simmilar arrays

```
api.request('/api/director-user', 'GET')
        .then(res => {
            if (res.status===200||res.status===201){ // success
                setPending([...pending, ...res.data.data]);
                console.log(res.data.data);
            }
        })

api.request('/api/company-user', 'GET')
        .then(res => {
            if (res.status===200||res.status===201){ // success
                setPending([...pending, ...res.data.data]);
                console.log(res.data.data);
            }
        })
```

but on result I getting error

[image]

your help would be so helpful.

btw this is two arrays for merge

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you also need to parse your response into json to read arrays
Try this:

```
api.request('/api/director-user', 'GET')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data)) // merge array here

api.request('/api/company-user', 'GET')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data)) //merge array here
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but I already solved. Problem was on memory data of array, as it saved incorrect type of array on testing this why I getted that kind of error. (Just refreshed the page and everything works)